# Data always filled by null in dbcontext in .net core 3.1 api

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

[image]Dears, I am using a dbfirst API . net core 3.1.
I created a migration file to apply stored procedure, and it is successfully created.

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        string procedure1 = @"CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Spz_order] @client varchar(10) as
        SELECT .....
        having ... =@client";
        migrationBuilder.Sql(procedure1);

    }
```

Then I created a model or class to receive the data in it

```
[NotMapped]
public partial class categoryStock
{
    public string model { get; }
    public int quantity { get;  }
    
}
```

Then a dbset

```
public virtual DbSet<categoryStock> Categories { get;}
```

Then in controller

```
 [HttpGet("getCategoryStock")]
    public async Task<List<categoryStock>> getCategoryStock(string cat)
    {

        using (_context)
        {
            if (_context.Categories != null)
            {
                var category =await _context.Categories
                .FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE Spz_order {0}", cat)
                .ToListAsync();
                return category.ToList();
            }
            return new List<categoryStock>();
        }
    }
```

BUT i always get data by null, can any one help me to solve this issue
Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps the issue is related to the NotMapped attribute, try to remove it. And, I have modified my reply, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

First, please check your database, make sure the data table contains records.

Second, please check your query statement in the stored procedure, make sure the query result is not null.

Third, please check the parameter value, make sure it is correct and you can find records according to the value.

**Edit**:

Perhaps the issue is related to the `[NotMapped]` attribute. The `NotMapped` attribute is used to specify that an entity or property is not to be mapped to a table or column in the database.

According to your code, I have created a model without using the `NotMapped` attribute, then, I can call the stored procedure and get the data.

Code as below:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var title = "G";
        var param = new SqlParameter("@Title", "Rio");
        //var movies = context.Movie
        //                .FromSqlRaw("GetMovies @Title", param)
        //                .ToList();
        var movies = context.Movie
                        .FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE GetMovies {0}", title)
                        .ToList();
        return View();
    }
```

The screenshot:

[image]

So, try to remove the `[NotMapped]` attribute.